# NGINX proxy pass - multiple entry pages from same server

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location, proxypass

I am using NGINX with proxy pass to act as reverse proxy. On the backend, we have only one server.

```
http://localhost:5000/index.html
http://localhost:5000/default.html
```

I have following condition in nginx.conf

```
location /one/ {
                        root http://localhost:5000;
                        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
                        index index.html
                        
                }

 location /two/ {
                        root http://localhost:5000;
                        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
                        index default.html
                         
                }
```

**Issue: Whether I request location `one` or location `two`, system always load the index.html page.**

What changes I need to make to fix this issue.

Comment: why dont you just do proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/default.html; in  /two/  entry?

Comment: also i think root entry is unnecessary.

Comment: @JackSparrow: I tried it. For some reason, default.html loads, but the subsequent resources does  not load. I get 404 error for remaining resources.

Comment: from my experience it works when you just do location /two/ { proxy_pass http://localhost:5000; }